# Kivy crashes on resume after screen lock

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm writing my first app with Kivy and am using Buildozer to deploy the app to Android. Although my app resumes when I switch between applications, if ever I lock my screen, the app does not resume at all.

Is there anything that I'm missing? The documentation seems to refer to this problem as a "bug" from previous versions. I'm using Kivy 1.10.0.

Here is what I did to handle pause/resume:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
    def on_pause(self):
        return True
    def on_resume(self):
        return sm
```

Answer (score 0):

You implemented the on_resume method wrong. Try this -

```
def on_resume(self):
  # Check if any data needs replacing, usually none 
  pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Put it back to pass, and unfortunately same behavior... I can switch between apps no problem, but lock/unlock returns a blank app...

Comment: When you turn off the screen of the mobile device, onPause() and onStop() are called, try implementing the onStop() fun, then keep an eye on the app's behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue and I have been pulling my hair out for about a week. After digging through the logs and changing my search terms, I found this issue: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/462

Raising the minimum Android API in buildozer.spec fixed the issue immediately! I changed mine from `android.minapi = 9` to `android.minapi = 15`  but you can experiment and find the right one for you.

Comment: Thanks man, I had kind of gave up on fixing this, as this really just was not working. Will try and get back to you! :)